# Read *.rtf files from database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server

I tried to read *.rtf files from an database, but I couldn't.

Here is the code which I used to add text in database from richTextBox

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MARIA-PC;Initial Catalog=Account;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[FILE] (File_name,The_text) VALUES (@File_name,@The_text)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@File_name", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@The_text", richTextBox1.Rtf);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

And the table I created 
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWKJI.jpg)

I tried a lot of solutions I found on the internet, but none of them where any good.

What I want to do is to display the text saved in database in the blank richTextBox.

Comment: Do you work with mysql or  (microsoft) sql server?

Comment: @Szeki yes, I work

Comment: but which one? the application connects to MySql or Microsoft Sql? Or both?

Comment: @Szeki MySql when I work on my pc, and Microsoft Sql when I work on another pc

Comment: I see, then I think it requires some work. SqlConnection class is for Microsoft SQL, for MySql, you'd need to get MySQL connector (it's a NuGet package).